# Should I mark a compiler-generated constructor as constexpr?

Tags: c++, c++11

Is there a difference between doing:

```
X() = default;
```

and

```
constexpr X() = default;
```

Default-constructing the class within constant expressions work fine, so is there a difference between these two examples? Should I use one over the other?

Comment: Somebody may very well provide a constructive answer, I'm not going to copy and paste from a site where I found information from. Here is a few pointers in the *constexpr constructor* part http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr

Comment: @woosah It will still be a valid answer if you do copy/paste.

Comment: @remyabel Oh I didn't know that. Thought it would be a bit like yahoo answers then :S

Comment: @woosah: Yeah a bit :( Usually better to cite the standard, but a well-attributed secondary source can be acceptable on occasion.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Since the implicit constructor is actually `constexpr` in your case…

> `[C++11: 12.1/6]:` *[..]* If that user-written default constructor would satisfy the requirements of a `constexpr` constructor (7.1.5), the implicitly-defined default constructor is `constexpr`. *[..]*
>
> `[C++11: 7.1.5/3]:` The definition of a `constexpr` function shall satisfy the following constraints:
>
> - it shall not be virtual (10.3);
> - its return type shall be a literal type;
> - each of its parameter types shall be a literal type;
> - **its function-body shall be** `= delete`, **`= default`**, or a *compound-statement* that contains only
>
>   - null statements,
>   - *static_assert-declarations*
>   - `typedef` declarations and *alias-declarations* that do not define classes or enumerations,
>   - *using-declarations*,
>   - *using-directives*,
>   - and exactly one return statement;
> - every constructor call and implicit conversion used in initializing the return value (6.6.3, 8.5) shall be one of those allowed in a constant expression (5.19).

… the declarations are actually equivalent:

> `[C++11: 8.4.2/2]:` An explicitly-defaulted function may be declared `constexpr` only if it would have been implicitly declared as `constexpr`, and may have an explicit *exception-specification* only if it is compatible (15.4) with the *exception-specification*
>   on the implicit declaration. **If a function is explicitly defaulted on its first declaration,**
>
> - **it is implicitly considered to be `constexpr` if the implicit declaration would be**,
> - it is implicitly considered to have the same *exception-specification* as if it had been implicitly declared (15.4), and
> - in the case of a copy constructor, move constructor, copy assignment operator, or move assignment operator, it shall have the same parameter type as if it had been implicitly declared.

So do either — it doesn't matter.

In the general case, if you definitely want a constructor to be `constexpr`, though, it may be wise to leave the keyword in so that you at least get a compiler error if it does not meet the criteria; leaving it out, you may get a non-`constexpr` constructor without realising it.