# constexpr defaulted default constructors

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-errors, c++14

I get compiler error by Clang 3.8 and GCC 5.3 if I want to declare my `default`-ed default constructors as `constexpr`. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20810378/should-i-mark-a-compiler-generated-constructor-as-constexpr) stackoverflow question it just should work fine:

```
struct A
{
    constexpr A() = default;

    int x;
};
```

however:

```
Error: defaulted definition of default constructor is not constexpr
```

Have you got any clue what is actually going on?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As it stands, x remains uninitialized, so the object can not be constructed at compile time.

You need to initialize x:

```
struct A
{
    constexpr A() = default;

    int x = 1;
};
```

Comment: Yeah I also figured it out in the meantime. That referenced SO question / answer is pretty incomplete and misleading.

Comment: @plasmacel the accepted answer covers the required info... in bold near the end it explains that if you do not write `constexpr` then the function is constexpr if and only if it meets the criteria for constexpr; and then the last paragraph explains that if you can write `constexpr` yourself if you want to get a compilation error when your function did not meet the criteria (as yours does not)