# Compiler generated default constructor with constexpr confusing behavior

Tags: c++, class, constexpr, default-constructor

Sample 1

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct A
{

    constexpr A() = default;
    T x;
};

int main(){
    static_assert(A<int>{}.x == int{}, "FAILED");
}
```

Sample 2

```cpp
struct A
{
    constexpr A() = default;
    int x;
};

int main(){
    static_assert(A{}.x == int{}, "Not Equal");
}
```

I am confused as to how the first sample compiles and passes the static assert, while the second one fails to compile as mentioned in the 
[constexpr defaulted default constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36392326/constexpr-defaulted-default-constructors)
with `Error: defaulted definition of default constructor is not constexpr`.

Tried reading the following but couldn't understand as to how first one works and other doesn't. http://eel.is/c++draft/class.ctor#class.default.ctor-4

> A default constructor that is defaulted and not defined as deleted is implicitly defined when it is odr-used ([basic.def.odr]) to create an object of its class type ([intro.object]), when it is needed for constant evaluation ([expr.const]), or when it is explicitly defaulted after its first declaration. The implicitly-defined default constructor performs the set of initializations of the class that would be performed by a user-written default constructor for that class with no ctor-initializer and an empty compound-statement. If that user-written default constructor would be ill-formed, the program is ill-formed. If that user-written default constructor would satisfy the requirements of a constexpr constructor ([dcl.constexpr]), the implicitly-defined default constructor is constexpr. Before the defaulted default constructor for a class is implicitly defined, all the non-user-provided default constructors for its base classes and its non-static data members are implicitly defined. [ Note: An implicitly-declared default constructor has an exception specification ([except.spec]). An explicitly-defaulted definition might have an implicit exception specification, see [dcl.fct.def]. — end note ]

Thank You!

Comment: If you declare a variable `constexpr A<int> z;`, you'll get a compiler error about `x` not being initialized, so I'm inclined to think it is a compiler bug.

Comment: I have tried it on `gcc, clang, mvsc` using godbolt.org and sample 1 compiled on all of them, so I don't think it is a bug. However I tried the line that you sent, it indeed doesn't work but if I try `constexpr A<int> z{}` then it works.

Answer (score 1):

The following can shed some light on the issue:

```
int main(){
    constexpr A<int> a;
}
```

Attempting to call the `constexpr` constructor produces this error (gcc):

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:12:22: error: uninitialized 'const a' [-fpermissive]
   12 |     constexpr A<int> a;
      |                      ^
<source>:4:8: note: 'const struct A<int>' has no user-provided default constructor
    4 | struct A
      |        ^
<source>:7:15: note: constructor is not user-provided because it is explicitly defaulted in the class body
    7 |     constexpr A() = default;
      |               ^
<source>:8:7: note: and the implicitly-defined constructor does not initialize 'int A<int>::x'
    8 |     T x;
      |       ^
```

However, if I am not missing something, the `constexpr` constructor should already be an error, because it cannot be `constexpr` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20810439/4117728)).

Both gcc and clang accept your code, but both produce an error for attempting to call the `constexpr` constructor. I suppose it is a compiler bug.

Comment: For sample 1, `constexpr A<std::string> a;` is giving me, `constexpr variable cannot have non-literal type 'const A<std::string>' (aka 'const A<basic_string<char> >')` which makes sense with reference to [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27123306/is-it-possible-to-use-stdstring-in-a-constexpr#:~:text=As%20of%20C%2B%2B20,any%20sequence%20of%20char%20objects.)

Comment: @CodeCollector oh, then I was wrong. will remove that part